# stack new not functioning as intended

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am new to haskell and am having trouble using `stack new` to create a new project.

I am using MACOSX (El Capitan) and after installing [GHC for Mac](https://ghcformacosx.github.io/) and installing [Stack using homebrew](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade.html#using-homebrew), I tried the following in `~/PROJECTS`

```
stack new my-project
```

This keeps giving me the following generic stack info

```
Usage: stack new ([--solver] | [--resolver RESOLVER] | [--prefer-lts] |
             [--prefer-nightly]) [--force] [--ignore-subdirs]
  Create a brand new project
```

I am using zsh - why is a the new `my-project` folder being created?

Note: `stack --version` outputs:

```
Version 0.1.2.0, Git revision 65246552936b7da4b64b38372feac903d96a8911
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack 0.1.2.0 doesn't take a package name. If you want to create a project called `my-project` (actually, a package called `new-template`) using that version, you can do something like

```
$ mkdir my-project
$ cd my-project/
$ stack new
```

This will generate some files in the `my-project` directory.

You can find more information with `stack new --help`.

Newer versions of Stack, however, require a package name. If you run `stack new` with Stack 1.0.0, for instance, you get something like

```
Usage: stack new PACKAGE_NAME ...
```

Both versions of Stack should work, but I guess your best option is to [upgrade Stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade.html#upgrade) (0.1.2.0 is from July 5, which is kind of old).

Comment: Thanks @jpvillaisaza! I used brew to install the stack so that future updates would be easier to manage. I did do `brew upgrade haskell-stack` but it doesn't seem to upgrade it to a more recent version. Any ideas on how to upgrade with brew? NOTE: when I run that `brew upgrade` command it mentions that `Error: haskell-stack 1.0.0 already installed` which means it should be the latest version. What is going on here in terms of the versions of stack being installed/ run?

Comment: @user4687531 What does `which stack` say? Your path might be getting an older version (I have an older one at `/usr/local/bin` and the new one at `~/.local/bin`, for instance), so make sure the path for the one you want has priority. Does `stack upgrade` work for you?

Comment: Ah `which stack` gives `/Applications/ghc-7.10.2.app/Contents/bin/stack` which is from [ghc for mac osx](http://ghcformacosx.github.io/). I need to be using the `brew` installed one which is here: `/usr/local/Cellar/haskell-stack/1.0.0`. I am guessing I just need to add the brew one to the front of my `$PATH` variable in zshrc?

Comment: @user4687531 Yes, make sure the one from brew comes first in the path.